# How to display in two divs the elements of an array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I encountered that recently.

 I have one array of strings:

```
a= ['apple', 'rice','pasta','orange']
```

There is a button to push random things into this array to save it after in DB, example:

```
a.push('carrot');a.save()
```

How to display it in the DOM in two separate divs(like apple, orange on the left, rice,pasta on the right, the split can be static, you don't need to teach angular to recognize every fruits in the world :P).

In my mind: filters or break into two variables and merge it back after?
My (dirty) solution was:

```
var a = getFromDb
$scope.b = _.filter(a,isFruit)
$scope.c = _.filter(a,isNotFruit)

Fruits : <div ng-repeat=fruit in b> {{fruit}}</div>
Others : <div ng-repeat=notFruit in c> {{notFruit}}</div>

$scope.save = function() {
  var a = $scope.b + $scope.c
  saveToDb(a)
}
```

But that look very ugly so I would love if someone had a more fancy way?

Answer (score 2):

Providing that you define on scope (or with controller-as):

```
$scope.a = ['apple', 'rice', 'pasta', 'orange']
```

Then in template you can simply split `a` into two parts and use them separately:

```
<div class="left">
  <span ng-repeat="fruit in a.slice(0, 2)">{{ fruit }}</span>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <span ng-repeat="fruit in a.slice(2)">{{ fruit }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a little bit harder then your answer. This would put apple, rice on the left and pasta, orange on the right.